# Loops in python does not loop through every line in file

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying to loop through every line in a text file and perform some actions. Right now I have a text file which contains this:

```
--- small modified --- #line 1
1,2,3                  #line 2
4,5,6                  #line 3
--- big modified ---   #line 4
7;8;9                  #line 5
10;11;12               #line 6
```

I am trying to parse line 2,3 into one file, and lines 5,6 into another file but right now, only lines 2 and 3 gets written into the file and idk why the "elif" statement is not run. I can't solve the logic error and would appreciate if someone could help me out.

Below is my code:

```
def convert_json(fileName):
    with open(fileName,'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if 'modified' and 'small' in line:
                for li in file:
                    fields1 = li.split(',')
                    if len(fields1) >= 3:
                            smallarr.append({
                            "a": fields1[0],
                            "b": fields1[1],
                            "c": fields1[2]
                                })
                            with open('smalljson.txt','w+') as small_file:
                                json.dump(smallarr, small_file)
                    else:
                        pass

            elif 'modified' and 'big' in line:
                for li in file:
                    fields2 = li.split(';')
                    if len(fields2) >= 3:
                            bigarr.append({
                            "w1": fields2[0],
                            "w2": fields2[1],
                            "w3": fields2[2],
                                })
                            with open('big.txt','w+') as big_file:
                                json.dump(bigarr, big_file)
                    else: 
                        pass



            else:
                print 'test'
```

Update: THis is my current code, I am able to do it but only for lines 2 and lines 5, other than s second for-loop i cannot think of another way to loop through the lines

```
def convert_json(fileName):
with open(fileName,'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        #if 'modified' in line and 'small' in line:
        if 'modified' in line and 'Small' in line:
            fields1 = next(file).split(',')
            if len(fields1) >= 3:
                smallarr.append({
                "a": fields1[0],
                "b": fields1[1],
                "c": fields1[2]
                })
                with open('smalljson.txt','w+') as small_file:
                    json.dump(smallarr, small_file)
            else:
                pass



        elif 'modified' in line and 'big' in line:
            fields2 = next(file).split(';')
            if len(fields2) >= 3:
                bigarr.append({
                "w1": fields2[0],
                "w2": fields2[1],
                "w3": fields2[2],
                })
                with open('bigwater.txt','w+') as big_file:
                    json.dump(bigarr, big_file)
            else:
                pass

        else:
            print 'test'
```

Comment: What have you tried to do to fix this? Have you tried inserting debug messages? Or stepping the program through with your IDE's debugger (if there is one)?

Comment: I tried playing around the loops, when i insert a break statement after the first else statement, only line 2, line 5 and 6 gets written. Line 3 is not written.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your inner for-loop will iterate through the entire file exhausting the iterator you are sharing across loops.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga any suggestions how to stop the inner for-loop from doing that ?

Comment: You can `break` out. But you should be doing this with exactly 1 for-loop.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if i only 1 for-loop, how do I filter out lines 1 and 4?

Comment: Check if they exist and deal with them accordingly. Use a flag.

Comment: You now have a new error in your latest update, string comparison is case sensitive so this `if 'modified' in line and 'Small' in line:` won't work because of the capital `S`.

Comment: @daragua noted, changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parsing logic need to be changed. Here is what code looks like, use it for reference in future improvements.

```
def file_parser(self):
    file_section = 0

    smallarr = []
    bigarr = []
    with open('data.txt') as in_file:
        for in_line in in_file:
            in_line = in_line.strip()

            if 'small' in in_line:
                file_section = 1
                continue
            elif 'big' in in_line:
                file_section = 2
                continue

            if file_section == 1:
                fields1 = in_line.split(',')
                if len(fields1) >= 3:
                    smallarr.append({
                        "a": fields1[0],
                        "b": fields1[1],
                        "c": fields1[2]
                    })
            elif file_section == 2:
                fields2 = in_line.split(';')
                if len(fields2) >= 3:
                    bigarr.append({
                        "w1": fields2[0],
                        "w2": fields2[1],
                        "w3": fields2[2],
                    })

    with open('small.txt', 'w+') as small_file:
        json.dump(smallarr, small_file)

    with open('big.txt', 'w+') as big_file:
        json.dump(bigarr, big_file)
```

Input data:

```
--- small modified ---
1,2,3
4,5,6
--- big modified ---
7;8;9
10;11;12
```

small.txt

```
[{"a": "1", "c": "3", "b": "2"}, {"a": "4", "c": "6", "b": "5"}]
```

big.txt

```
[{"w3": "9", "w2": "8", "w1": "7"}, {"w3": "12", "w2": "11", "w1": "10"}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It is a working program now :)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
elif 'modified' and 'big' in line:
```

into

```
elif 'modified' in line and 'big' in line:
```

Comment: I tried, does not seem to work. Still the "elif" statement is not executed

Comment: change your logic, and remove "for li in file:"

Comment: Your first `if` condition suffers from the same defect.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code.

Firstly you are repeating yourself. The big and small cases don't vary enough to justify the code duplication.

Secondly, while I understand what you're trying to do with `next(file)`, you'd still need to loop that instruction in some way to go get the next lines. But wait, you're already doing that exactly with `for line in file`.

Finally, at each loop, you're reopening the same file and redumping an ever increasing array. This is wasteful IO. If you're trying to stream from `file` into `bigwater.txt` and `smalljson.txt` and not storing too much stuff in memory, this is the wrong approach since json.dump can't be used to stream data.

Here's my take at it:

```
def convert_json(fileName):
    big = []
    small = []
    with open(fileName,'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()
            if line.startswith("--"):
                if "big" in line:
                    array = big
                    keys = ["w1", "w2", "w3"]
                    sep = ";"
                else:
                    array = small
                    keys = ["a", "b", "c"]
                    sep = ","
                continue

            values = line.split(sep)
            # todo: make sure sizes match
            mapping = dict(zip(keys, values))
            array.append(mapping)

    with open('smalljson.txt','w') as small_file:
        json.dump(small, small_file)
    with open('bigwater.txt','w') as big_file:
        json.dump(big, big_file)
```